# Access mongodb+nodejs from javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm running a server with nodejs+mongodb:

```
let MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb", { useNewUrlParser: true } ),

(async () =>{
   let client;
   try {
      client = await MongoClient;
      ...
```

I'm creating some data-visualizations and I need a simple way to access my backend data from javascript, is this possible? Ideally I would like full access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to build a bridge, e.g. using a REST API:

```
 // server.js
 // npm install express, body-parser, mongodb
 const app = require("express")();
 const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
 const db = require("mongodb").MongoClient.connect(/*...*/);

 app.use(bodyParser.json());

 app.post("/findOne", async (req, res) => {
  try {
   const connection = await db;
   const result = await connection.findOne(req.body);
   if(!result) throw new Error("Not found!");
   res.status(200).json(result);
  } catch(error) {
   res.status(500).json(error);
  }
 });

 // ... all those other methods ...

 app.listen(80);
```

That way you can easily connect to it on the client:

```
 // client.js
 function findOne(query) {
   const result =  await fetch("/findOne/", {
     method: "POST",
     body: JSON.stringify(query),
     headers:{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     }
   });

   if(!result.ok) throw await result.json();

   return await result.json();
}
```

---

Note: I hope you are aware that you also allow some strangers to play with your database if you do not validate the requests properly / add authentication.

Comment: you missed a "dot", `bodyParser.json()`

Answer (score 1):

For security purposes you should **never** do this, but hypothetically you could make an AJAX endpoint or WebSockets server on the node application that passes the input straight to mongoDB and takes the output straight back to the client.

It would be a much better practice to write a simple API using AJAX requests or WS to prevent the user from compromising your database.

Comment: I know, there is no sensitive data in this database and I will only run it on my local machine...

Comment: In that case, just do a JSON.parse on an http request, dump it into a query, and send the results of the query as the http response.